# How can I set the constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I have a problem with my constraints.

I want to do something like this:
[image: example]

And I want the UIImage size (and labels) increases or decreases depending on the iPhone device used.

I tried using 'Aspect Radio', 'Equal Widths'... but I can not do that the size of the images are adjusted.

How can I set the constrains to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it the case that you have exactly two items that each contain an `UIImageView`, three `UILabel`s, and a `UIButton`?  Or are those cells inside of a `UICollectionView`?

Comment: I have only these elements in a UIViewController.

Comment: Aspect Radio constraints should do the job. Make sure your UIImage are set to ScaleAspectFit

Answer (score 0):

You could put the labels and buttons inside a view the same size as your UIImageView. Set both views to Equal Width, then set the leading space constraint on the UIImageView, the trailing space constraint on the other view, and the space in between the two views. Finally, I would set an aspect ratio on each one so the height will stay proportional as the width is adjusted to different phone sizes.